# How to set color of UITableView _UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicolor

I have UITableView with a backgroundView set to a UIImageView. The UIImageView uses an image with gradient pattern.

```
let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: tableView.frame)
imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "background")
tableView.backgroundView = imageView
```

When I delete rows, the table automatically inserts a white row. When I pause the app with Xcode to view the drawn components, it shows that it's a _UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell.

How do I get the _UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell to use a clear background color?

I have tried setting all components in the tableview to use clear colors but that didn't seem to work

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Here is how I am deleting:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.budget = budget.removingTransaction(at: indexPath.row-1)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
}
```

[image: Table View]

[image: row deletion]

[image: _UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell]

Comment: please also share the code, related to delete the tableview cell

Comment: The problem is that this is not your class. There is no way to mess with it. If you _do_ manage to mess with it, you are likely to get dinged when you try to submit the app. This seems like a good use case to file an enhancement request with Apple, but until they give you an official way, you're probably just stuck.

Comment: Not sure why a cell would get inserted when you delete a cell. If it is just during animation then I think it might be because the default colour of the `tableView.backgroundColor` is white, set it to match your cell colour.

Comment: @matt I'm not looking to modify the cell directly, I'm just looking to find a way to get it to be clear. Maybe by configuring the tableview some why.

Comment: @user1046037 I already set the backgroundColor to clear

Comment: well if you set it to clear, then it would be like the tableView's background is transparent and would take the colour of the view underlying the table view. So set it to red just to debug and understand

Comment: user1046037, I embed the tableview in a uiview and set the uiview's background and everything in the tableview upwards to clear and got the same results

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's due to updating table after delete your row.
Try this code:-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        self.budget = budget.removingTransaction(at: indexPath.row-1)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you,
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't fix it. I have filed a bug report though https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=39555825

Answer (score 0):

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        clearWhiteBackgroundWhenDelete()
    }
}

func clearWhiteBackgroundWhenDelete() {
    if let whiteBackgroudViewClass = NSClassFromString("_UISwipeToDeletePlaceholderCell") {
       _ = tableView.subviews.map { if $0.isKind(of: whiteBackgroudViewClass) { $0.backgroundColor = .clear } }
    }
}
```